# Can't loop embeded sound in flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
[Embed('sounds/music1.mp3')]
public var Music1:Class;

[Embed('sounds/music2.mp3')]
public var Music2:Class;

[Embed('sounds/music3.mp3')]
public var Music3:Class;

public var music:Array;
public var currentSongIndex:int;

    public function complete():void {

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
        stage.frameRate = 32;
        music = new Array();
        music.push(new Music1());
        music.push(new Music2());
        music.push(new Music3());

        currentSongIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * music.length );
        var playFirst:SoundAsset = music[currentSongIndex] as SoundAsset;
        playFirst.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, songFinished);
        playFirst.play();
    }

    public function PlaySongFromIndex(songIndex:int){
        var playFirst:SoundAsset = music[currentSongIndex] as SoundAsset;
        playFirst.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, songFinished);
        playFirst.play();
    }

    public function songFinished(e:Event){
        if(currentSongIndex < music.Length){
            currentSongIndex++;
            PlaySongFromIndex(currentSongIndex);
        } else {
            currentSongIndex=0;
        }
    }
```

I'am trying to loop the embeded music, but only the first random song is played, and then is only silence...can't understand why the next song doesn't play, can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

In the conditional in your `complete` handler you're testing for `music.Length` (note the upper-case L) which will throw an error as soon as it executes. You also need to fix the test which will currently allow the index to increment beyond the range of the array (remember that array elements are 0-indexed).

Also, since you don't call the `PlaySongFromIndex` method from the `else` condition the program won't progress past the first song about once in every three times.

Try updating your code with the following:

```
public function songFinished(e:Event){
    if(currentSongIndex < music.length - 1){
        currentSongIndex++;
    } else {
        currentSongIndex=0;
    }
    PlaySongFromIndex(currentSongIndex);
}
```

Comment: i've changed to this, but after the first song, still the next doesn't play... can't figure out why

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Try putting a trace statement or breakpoint in the song complete handler to make sure that's executing.

Comment: Actually, see updated answer. Your conditional is allowing the index to go out of range of your array and you are testing for music.Length rather than music.length which will throw an error as soon as it executes.